I need help finding the value of this limit. spe$\lim_{n \to \infty}4^n \psi^{(2)}(2^n)$
I need help finding the value of this limit.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}4^n \psi^{(2)}(2^n)$$
I know
$$\psi^{(2)}(2^n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{-2}{(k+2^n)^3}  $$
therfore :
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}4^n \psi^{(2)}(2^n)=\lim_{n \to \infty}4^n\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{-2}{(k+2^n)^3}$$
Using mathematica :
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}4^n \psi^{(2)}(2^n)=-1$$
Is there a way to calculate that limit? This is not my homework, I am trying to learn by myself and found this problem, I appreciate your interest

Let $2^n=t$ and consider the problem of
$$f(t)=t^2 \,\psi ^{(2)}(t)$$
Use the asymptotics (have a look here)
$$\psi ^{(2)}(t)=-\frac 1 {t^2}-\frac 1 {t^3}-\frac 1 {2t^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^6}\right)$$

Yes , Thank you

This is a method by Noureddine Sma
let $x=2^n$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}4^n\psi^{(2)}(2^n) = \lim_{x\to \infty} x^2\psi^{(2)}(x) $$
we have :
$$\frac{(m-1)!}{x^m}+\frac{m!}{2x^{m+1}} \le (-1)^{m+1}\psi^{(m)}(x) \le \frac{(m-1)!}{x^m}+\frac{m!}{x^{m+1}}$$
therfore:
$$\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3} \le -\psi^{(2)}(x) \le \frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x^3}$$
$$-1-\frac{1}{x} \ge x^2\psi^{(2)}(x) \ge -1-\frac{2}{x}$$
Therfore:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}4^n\psi^{(2)}(2^n) = \lim_{x\to \infty} x^2\psi^{(2)}(x) \lim_{x\to \infty}-1-\frac{2}{x}=\lim_{x\to \infty} -1-\frac{1}{x}=-1$$
